# How would I query multiple MySQL tables based upon a certain condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one that holds a lot of rows of data, and one that holds which rows a user has used to date. How do I use a single query that allows me to pull 3 items from the main table but only rows that the given user has not seen before.

Example tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `main_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into `main_index` set `id`='1', `name`='something1';
insert into `main_index` set `id`='2', `name`='something2';
insert into `main_index` set `id`='3', `name`='something3';
insert into `main_index` set `id`='4', `name`='something4';
insert into `main_index` set `id`='5', `name`='something5';

CREATE TABLE `seen_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(12),
  `row_id` int(12),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into `seen_index` set `user_id`='1', `row_id`='3';
insert into `seen_index` set `user_id`='1', `row_id`='5';
insert into `seen_index` set `user_id`='2', `row_id`='1';
insert into `seen_index` set `user_id`='2', `row_id`='3';
insert into `seen_index` set `user_id`='2', `row_id`='4';
```

Using a user_id of '1' for this, the query should return: 1, 2, 4

Comment: I don't see how `user_id=1` matches up to expected outcome `1, 2, 4`

Comment: based on the 2 tables I gave, user_id (1) has seen id 3 and 5 from the main_index table before, according to the seen_index. So the query would return the rows from main_index that user_id (1) has not seen yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will work:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
main_index
WHERE
id NOT IN (
    SELECT row_id FROM seen_index WHERE user_id = 1
)
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55ad4/4/0)

An alternative method is:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
main_index
WHERE
NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM seen_index WHERE user_id = 1 AND row_id = main_index.id
)
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55ad4/6/0)